# How do I get the font 'Myriad Pro' for linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I've done some googling on this and I can't seem to find this font for ubuntu. I believe that it's an adobe font.

Comment: Better asked on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Download Adobe Reader, the font is included.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, regular truetype fonts can be used on Ubuntu without any problems, so if you find a version of it for Windows, it should probably work for you too.